# Enforce referential integrity for FriendRequest table that has UserA and UserB

Tags: database-design, referential-integrity

I have a table called `User` that has `UserName` as a primary key.

I want to establish a relationship with enforced referential integrity between `User` and `FriendRequest`.

`FriendRequest` has the following: `RequestID`, `UserNameA`, `UserNameB`, `Accepted`.
`UserNameA` is the sender of the request and `UserNameB` is the recpient. Accepting requests sets the relationship between A and B to friends. Rejecting deletes the row. No answer means that Accepted is set to FALSE.

The problem is that I can't enforce integrity and without it I can enter any user name for `UserNameA` and `UserNameB` even if that particular `UserName` does not even exist on UserProfile.

Is there a way to make my `FriendRequest` table work in Access?

[image]

In this screenshot, before I added the second row for relationships, the relation type was displayed as one-to-many. As soon as I add the second relationship it becomes one-to-one.

**EDIT**

Alright, I did it again (carefully this time). You were right that I did only create one relationship instead of two. However, I get this wierd duplication of the same table. Please take a look at the second screenshot. As you can see UserProfile was duplicated to UserProfile_1. But my list of actual existing tables only show that UserProfile exists. What exactly is UserProfile_1?

[image]

Comment: What's the problem? Create two foreign key constraints on tble FriendRequest (referencing User). What doesn't?

Comment: For some reason I can't enforce referential integrity to username for 2 foreign keys (A and B). But I can do it for one. So UserNameA can be enforced but UserNameB wont. Or I can make them both unenforced foreign keys but then I can add anything for usernameA and usernameB. So if craig1 does not exist in User, I am allowed to add that nonexistent user to usernameA or usernameB.

Comment: You need to add 2 foreign keys, as @tombom suggested. One FK for `UserNameA REFERENCES Users (UserName)` and another for `UserNameB REFERENCES Users (UserName)`. There surely is a way to do this in Access.

Comment: It won't work. Would I have to do this with custom SQL statements?

Comment: What do you mean with "not work"? What did you try and what error did you get?

Comment: I forgot to mention I took a screenshot. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Oh, I see the image now. What you did was trying to create one relationship with 2 columns. Don't do that. First create one relationship, only with `UserNameA` and then another one, with `UserNameB`.

Comment: Does that essentially mean I need to have a UserA and UserB table?

Comment: Please read my new comment and the second screenshot I posted (after taking your advice and re-doing it carefully).

Comment: You did it fine. Access shows tables like this (duplicates, triplicates, etc) when there are more than 2 or more relationships between two tables.

Comment: It also seems to work when I teat it

Comment: That was a typo and I don't have the edit feature. It also seems to work when i test it. Consider this solved and feel free to publish your answer so I can mark it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can answer it yourself by moving the "EDIT" part to an answer.